# Installing cuDNN on elementry os gives segmentaion fault

Tags: nvidia, cudnn

I'm installing cuDNN from official nvidia site. I already installed CUDA.

Following commands were used during installtion:

```
 tar -xzvf cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.tgz
 sudo cp cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include
 sudo cp cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64                           
 sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h
```

Everything is fine upto here. Now when I run this command:

```
 /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
```

It gives me segmentaion fault. I can't figure out the problem !

Comment: why r u running this ` /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*`? the first step commands already installed cudnn

Answer (score -1):

I also meet the problem, and I have tried the deb package, but it doesn't work.

But after I rebooting the system, the problem doesn't appear.